# D3.js pie layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making a pie layout in d3.js v4 and its giving me this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: colors is not defined at SVGPathElement. (main.js:37) at SVGPathElement. (d3.min.js:2) at dt.ol [as each] (d3.min.js:4) at dt.ul [as attr] (d3.min.js:4) at main.js:36

here is my code:

```js
var width = 400
    , height = 400
    , radius = 200,
    color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var piedata = [
    {
        label: "Barot"
        , value: 50
    }
    , {
        label: "Gerard"
        , value: 50
    }
    , {
        label: "Jennifer"
        , value: 50
    }
]

var pie = d3.pie()
.value(function(d){
    return d.value;
})

var arc = d3.arc()
.outerRadius(radius)

var myChart = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height)
.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate('+(width-radius)+','+(height-radius)+')')
.selectAll('path').data(pie(piedata))
.enter().append('path')
.attr('fill',function(d, i){
    return colors(i);
})
.attr('d', arc)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bar Chart</title>
    <meta charset="8-UTF">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="css/style.css"> </head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Pie Layout</h2>
       <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your scale is named `color`, not `colors`.

Comment: oh okay thank you, the pie layout appeared but its missing an arc, it gave me this  Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "….99999999999997LNaN,NaNZ".
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "….00000000000007LNaN,NaNZ".
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "…420595e-14,-200LNaN,NaNZ".